# general protection fault when container running in Kubernates

Tags: c++, docker, kubernetes

I have a C++ applications that runs in a Docker container. I've used it for a long time managing it with the Docker daemon and never had a single crash. Now it is about a month that I've migrated the application to a Kubernetes cluster. The application runs as expected, however, randomly it crashes without outputting any message. Looking dmesg output, I get these errors:

```
[Wed Mar  9 13:49:33 2022] traps: STK2_imgserver-[1912675] general protection fault ip:7fa61d404941 sp:7fa50b7fdb50 error:0 in libc-2.31.so[7fa61d404000+178000]
[Wed Mar  9 13:49:38 2022] traps: STK2_imgserver-[2026551] general protection fault ip:7f7998e57941 sp:7ffcbdade8d0 error:0 in libc-2.31.so[7f7998e57000+178000]
[Wed Mar  9 13:49:57 2022] traps: STK2_imgserver-[2027266] general protection fault ip:7fd59ece0941 sp:7ffe6214f180 error:0 in libc-2.31.so[7fd59ece0000+178000]
[Wed Mar  9 13:50:29 2022] traps: STK2_imgserver-[2028288] general protection fault ip:7f203541b941 sp:7fff505e7820 error:0 in libc-2.31.so[7f203541b000+178000]
```

Is someone aware of a problem that could arise only if an application is running in a Kubernetes pod and not in a Docker container?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is a frequent cause of this.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and get a stack trace? Are the docker containers & kubernetes pods running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, the docker container and Kubernetes pod run on the same machine. About attaching the debugger, I should investigate how to do that.

Comment: I can add that in these days I get the same error also when the application is running in a Docker container (and not in Kubernetes). Therefore, what stated in this question does not hold and probably there is a bug in the C++ application.